# Как удалить лишний span в CF7 не удаляя спан эррора?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, contact-form7

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', function($content) {
$content = preg_replace('/<(span).*?class="\s*(?:.*\s)?wpcf7-form-control-wrap(?:\s[^"]+)?\s*"[^\>]*>(.*)<\/\1>/i', '\2', $content);

return $content;
});
```

этот код удаляет все спаны , а мне нужно , чтобы спан эррора оставил , как сделать ? помогите, пожалуйста, очень надо

```
    <div class="form-item">
  <p>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
 <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" 
    size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text 
   wpcf7- 
    Bvalidates-as-required input_info wpcf7-not-valid" 
  aria-- 
      required="true" aria-invalid="true" 
   placeholder="Name">
     <span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid-t 
 ip">Required field.</span>
    </span>
     <label class="input-label"> Name </label>
   </p>
  </div>

 <div class="form-item">
  <p>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
 <input type="text" name="your-name" value="" 
  size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text 
wpcf7- 
validates-as-required input_info wpcf7-not-valid" aria- 
  required="true" aria-invalid="true" 
 placeholder="Name">
      <span role="alert" class="wpcf7-not-valid- 
 tip">Required field.</span>
      </span>
    <label class="input-label"> Name </label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Пришлите полностью разметку блока

Comment: Добавил в вопросе

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731560/how-can-i-remove-the-span-wrapper-in-contact-form-7

Comment: Мне нужно спан эрора оставить

Comment: Не майся фигнёй. Если спаны ломают вёрстку, то работай со стилями. а не удаляй их.

Comment: @SeVlad да я уже +- решил проблему, пришлось заюзать все свои знания Jquery